# C++: How to check if a file/directory is readable? (PHP equivalent: is_readable)

Tags: c++, linux, boost, filesystems

I am trying to validate a directory with C++.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

> bool is_readable ( string $filename )  
>  Tells whether a file (or directroy) exists and is readable.

What would be the equivalent of the above in C++?

I am already using the boost/filesystem library to check that the directory exists.
I have checked the documentation:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm
 but I cannot find the equivalent of PHP's is_readable().

If it is not possible with the boost/filesystem library, what method would you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Since you've tagged the question "Linux", there is a POSIX function to check if the file is readable/writable/executable by the user of the current process. See `man 2 access`.

   ```
   int access(const char *pathname, int mode);
   ```

   For example,

   ```
   if (-1 == access("/file", R_OK))
   {
       perror("/file is not readable");
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, if you need portability, try to actually open the file for reading (e.g. `std::ifstream`). If it succeeds, the file is readable. Likewise, for directories, use `boost::filesystem::directory_iterator`, if it succeeds, directory is readable.

Comment: Thanks. A quick follow up question: I don't have the relevant man pages installed ("No manual entry for access in section 2"). Would you know the package name to install on Debian/Kubuntu?

Comment: imho the correct way is no. 2 anyway, you have no guarantee if access returns success that it is still readable when you rty to read from it

Comment: @jk yes, there is always a TOCTOU race condition possible if you try to open it later, but it works for one-off reporting purposes (i.e. when only a check is needed).

Comment: Yes, in this case, I don't actually want to read anything, but check that the directory is readable before saving a setting.

Answer (score 4):

Most operating systems provide stat().